# Sharepoint 2013 Add solution

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

I am getting below error when I tried to install the WSP in staging environment.

> Add-SPSolution : Operation is not valid due to the current state of
>   the object. At line:1 char:1
>   + Add-SPSolution  -LiteralPath "D:\StagePackage\SharePoint.ServiceSett ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...dletAddSolution:SPCmdletAddSolution) [
>   Add-SPSolution], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletAddSolution

I am not sure what is the exact issue here, I tried to install the same package in my dev/test environment its working fine

Below is the ULS log

> Deleting the SPPersistedObject, SPSolutionLanguagePack
>   Name=0.   5f1402fb-84e7-41d1-abeb-da9cdc500246
>
> Deleting the SPPersistedObject, SPSolution
>   Name=sharepoint.mysettings.wsp.   5f1402fb-84e7-41d1-abeb-da9cdc500246
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the
>   current state of the object.     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.ISPPersistedStoreProvider.GetParent(SPPersistedObject
>   persistedObject)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSolutionLanguagePack.get_DisplayName()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSolutionLanguagePack.SetSolutionFile(SPFarmSolutionPackage
>   solnPackage, String path, String solutionName, Boolean isRestore)
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSolution.AddLanguagePack(SPFarmSolutionPackage
>   solnPackage, String path, UInt32 lcid, String name, Boolean isRestore)
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSolutionCollection.Add(String
>   path, String name, UInt32 lcid, Boolean isRestore)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSolutionCollection.Add(String
>   path, UInt32 lcid)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPNewCmdletBase`1.InternalProcessRecord()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdlet.ProcessRecord()  5f1402fb-84e7-41d1-abeb-da9cdc500246
>
> Error Category: InvalidData    Target Object 
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletAddSolution  Details  NULL 
>   RecommendedAction NULL    5f1402fb-84e7-41d1-abeb-da9cdc500246

I tried deploying the package with stsadm command also and there also I am getting error. Its 2013 solution and scoped at farm level

I am completely running out of ideas can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: Did VS created the package without any errors or warnings?